# auto update formula based on another cell excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have formula: =COUNTBLANK(E1:E3)

I want the e3 to continue to auto increment when I add a column to A4.

All help and input is highly appreciated

I am using Excel 2010

Adding more details of what i need to complete this issue:

I've Merged cells A-B, C-D, E-F. A-b = item, c-d = item serial, e-f is date item sold.

```
Item     |    Serial    |    Date Sold
1             001            01/10/2016
2        |    867       |               
3        |    999       |    02/11/2014
```

Items in store: 1

If item sold date is blank that means my item should still be in store.

So when I add a new item in A-B I need to auto update My formula reading date item sold. So I have formula =COUNTBLANK(E1:E3) which is dependant on A1-Axx depending on how many items I have in store.

If I add item to A4 I need my countblank formula to see I added a new item and Start counting E4 as a blank item now and show, 2 items in store..

Comment: If either the answers below answered your question then please mark the one that best answered as the correct answer, by clicking the check mark by the correct answer.  this is something only you can do.  It will close the question as being answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will grow as the data grows:

```
=COUNTBLANK(E1:INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)))
```

If your data in Column A is a string then use this instead:

```
=COUNTBLANK(E1:INDEX(E:E,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)))
```

Comment: When using this formula I get #N/A As output. I noticed when using my colum header my data starts at e2 not e1...I modified formula to =COUNTBLANK(E2:INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))) however same output. any insight? ty so far!

Comment: Are your Items, numbers or text?

Comment: format is set to date on date sold and for item it is text and numbers like 2015 ford exhaust or just ford exhaust format set to general on item

Comment: No column A, is it a number or a string?

Answer (score 2):

```
=COUNTBLANK(OFFSET($A$1$,0,0,COUNTA(A:A),1))
```

Should count the number of blanks in the column E that match your data.

You could also go with:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTA(E:E)
```

That assumes there is nothing under your table

Comment: FWIW Offset is a volatile function, in that it will calculate every time excel recalculates.  If used just once it will not slow down excel but if there are hundreds it will add to the recalc time.  Non volatile function only recalc when the data to which they refer change.  Again as this is a one off equation it would not make much of a difference.

Comment: note to self, avoid offset if used repeatedly.  is count volatile?  If you throw an offset function into a named range, will the named range be recalculated on ever sheet recalc as well?

Comment: No to your first question and yes to your second.  There have been very few times I could not replace offset and Indirect with INDEX.

Comment: I really like your second equation, it is simple and allows for full column reference.

Comment: apparently I work both ends of the spectrum for possible formulas!